# Error when sharing a CSV file saved in internal storage

Tags: java, android, csv, storage

I'm creating a contact tracing application using Java, the results of tracing are saved as `detections.csv` inside `/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.idcta.proj.app/Sensor/` folder.

[image]

I'm trying to share this file on a button click, and my Manifest looks like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.idcta.proj.app">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
   />

    <application
        android:name="com.idcta.proj.app.AppDelegate"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
.....</appliction>
```

`provider_paths.xml` looks like:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    </paths>
```

and inside my `Contactlogs.java` file inside the onCreate method

```
//request permissions for storage
requestPermissions();
            
//share button event
        
btn_share =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_sharelogs);
btn_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()   {

     public void onClick(View v)  {

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),"detection.csv");
        Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Contactlogs.this,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider",file);
            
        Intent fileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         fileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | 
         Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            
         fileIntent.setType("text/*");
         fileIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
         Toast.makeText(Contactlogs.this," "+path,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(fileIntent, "Send"));
                
       }
     });
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
E/ContentProviderNative: onTransact error from {P:29044;U:1000}
E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://com.idcta.proj.app.provider/external_files/detection.csv from pid=29044, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:873)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:714)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:245)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:120)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1165)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1134)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

My Build.Gradle settings:

```
  compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.idcta.proj.app'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.2.0"
```

Comment: `the results of tracing are saved as detections.csv inside appdirectory/Sensor folder.` Unclear where that would be. Please tell full path.

Comment: `Internal shared storage\Android\media\com.idcta.proj.app\Sensor` is the directory shown in the windows file explorer

Comment: Can be. But i asked for full path on Android device.

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.idcta.proj.app/Sensor/detection.csv` this one

Comment: `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),"detection.csv")` Well then look at the value of `file.getAbsolutePath()`. Is it the same?

Comment: OMG you're a  life saver. the path shown in file was wrong. i added  `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),
                        "Android/media/com.idcta.proj.app/Sensor/detection.csv");` and it worked! thank you, please add this answer and ill mark this as correct.

Comment: Remove the `.getAbsolutePath()` from your statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > detections.csv inside /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.idcta.proj.app/Sensor/ folder.

That you got using `getExternalMediaDirs()[0]`.

```
 /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.idcta.proj.app/Sensor/detections.csv
```

So what did you code to have that path while saving?

Now when you want to serve the file you could use:

```
File file = new File(getExternalMediaDirs()[0], "Sensor/detections.csv");
```

Now you are hard coding your package name in the path.

Hardcoding should be avoided.